# Sum a column based on groupby and condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and some columns. I want to sum column "Gap" where time is in some time slots.

```
   region.    date.   time.     gap
0   1   2016-01-01  00:00:08    1
1   1   2016-01-01  00:00:48    0
2   1   2016-01-01  00:02:50    1
3   1   2016-01-01  00:00:52    0
4   1   2016-01-01  00:10:01    0
5   1   2016-01-01  00:10:03    1
6   1   2016-01-01  00:10:05    0
7   1   2016-01-01  00:10:08    0
```

I want to sum gap column. I have time slots in dict like that.

```
'slot1': '00:00:00', 'slot2': '00:10:00', 'slot3': '00:20:00'
```

Now after summation, above dataframe should like that.

```
 region.    date.       time.      gap
0   1   2016-01-01  00:10:00/slot1  2
1   1   2016-01-01  00:20:00/slot2  1
```

I have many regions and 144 time slots from 00:00:00 to 23:59:49. I have tried this.

```
regres=reg.groupby(['start_region_hash','Date','Time'])['Time'].apply(lambda x: (x >= hoursdict['slot1']) & (x <= hoursdict['slot2'])).sum()
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert column `time` to `datetimes` with [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by `10Min`, then convert to strings `HH:MM:SS`:

```
d = {'slot1': '00:00:00', 'slot2': '00:10:00', 'slot3': '00:20:00'}
d1 = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.floor('10Min').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
   region        date      time  gap
0       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    1
1       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    0
2       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    1
3       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    0
4       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    0
5       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    1
6       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    0
7       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    0
```

Aggregate `sum` and last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) values by dictionary with swapped keys with values:

```
regres = df.groupby(['region','date','time'], as_index=False)['gap'].sum()
regres['time'] = regres['time'] + '/' + regres['time'].map(d1)
print (regres)
   region        date            time  gap
0       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00/slot1    2
1       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00/slot2    1
```

If want display next `10Min` slots:

```
d = {'slot1': '00:00:00', 'slot2': '00:10:00', 'slot3': '00:20:00'}
d1 = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}

times = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.floor('10Min')
df['time'] = times.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['time1'] = times.add(pd.Timedelta('10Min')).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
   region        date      time  gap     time1
0       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    1  00:10:00
1       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    0  00:10:00
2       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    1  00:10:00
3       1  2016-01-01  00:00:00    0  00:10:00
4       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    0  00:20:00
5       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    1  00:20:00
6       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    0  00:20:00
7       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00    0  00:20:00

regres = df.groupby(['region','date','time','time1'], as_index=False)['gap'].sum()
regres['time'] = regres.pop('time1') + '/' + regres['time'].map(d1)
print (regres)
   region        date            time  gap
0       1  2016-01-01  00:10:00/slot1    2
1       1  2016-01-01  00:20:00/slot2    1
```

EDIT:

Improvement for floor and convert to strings is use bining by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) or `searchsorted`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

bins = pd.timedelta_range('00:00:00', '24:00:00', freq='10Min')
labels = np.array(['{}'.format(str(x)[-8:]) for x in bins])
labels = labels[:-1]

df['time1'] = pd.cut(df['time'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
df['time11'] = labels[np.searchsorted(bins, df['time'].values) - 1]
```

Comment: Is is slow process? taking too much time in my data of more than 600k records.

Comment: @shahidhamdam - need more time, but possible be faster

Comment: @shahidhamdam - one thing - you need second solution or first?

Comment: I need first solutions but one thing more. I also want to count rows in a time slot. for example in slot1, there are 4 rows. can you help me in that?

Comment: @shahidhamdam - Use `regres = df.groupby(['region','date','time','time1'], as_index=False).size().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: Can you please answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767342/append-column-values-to-match-length-with-other-data

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about approaching this problem is converting your `time` column to the values you want first, and then doing a `groupby sum` of the `time` column.

The below code shows the approach I've used. I used `np.select` to include in as many conditions and condition options as I want. After I have converted `time` to the values I wanted, I did a simple `groupby sum` 
None of the fuss of formatting time or converting strings etc is really needed. Simply let pandas dataframe handle it intuitively.

```
#Just creating the DataFrame using a dictionary here
regdict = {
        'time': ['00:00:08','00:00:48','00:02:50','00:00:52','00:10:01','00:10:03','00:10:05','00:10:08'],
        'gap': [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],}

df = pd.DataFrame(regdict)


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #This is the library you require for np.select function    

#Add in all your conditions and options here
condlist = [df['time']<'00:10:00',df['time']<'00:20:00'] 
choicelist = ['00:10:00/slot1','00:20:00/slot2'] 

#Use np.select after you have defined all your conditions and options
answerlist = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
print (answerlist)
['00:10:00/slot1' '00:10:00/slot1' '00:10:00/slot1' '00:10:00/slot1'
'00:20:00/slot2' '00:20:00/slot2' '00:20:00/slot2' '00:20:00/slot2']

#Assign answerlist to df['time']
df['time'] = answerlist
print (df)
       time  gap
0  00:10:00    1
1  00:10:00    0
2  00:10:00    1
3  00:10:00    0
4  00:20:00    0
5  00:20:00    1
6  00:20:00    0
7  00:20:00    0

df = df.groupby('time', as_index=False)['gap'].sum()
print (df) 
       time  gap
0  00:10:00    2
1  00:20:00    1
```

If you wish to keep the original time you can instead do `df['timeNew'] = answerlist` and then filter from there.

```
df['timeNew'] = answerlist
print (df)
       time  gap         timeNew
0  00:00:08    1  00:10:00/slot1
1  00:00:48    0  00:10:00/slot1
2  00:02:50    1  00:10:00/slot1
3  00:00:52    0  00:10:00/slot1
4  00:10:01    0  00:20:00/slot2
5  00:10:03    1  00:20:00/slot2
6  00:10:05    0  00:20:00/slot2
7  00:10:08    0  00:20:00/slot2

#Use transform function here to retain all prior values
df['aggregate sum of gap'] = df.groupby('timeNew')['gap'].transform(sum)
print (df) 
       time  gap         timeNew  aggregate sum of gap
0  00:00:08    1  00:10:00/slot1                     2
1  00:00:48    0  00:10:00/slot1                     2
2  00:02:50    1  00:10:00/slot1                     2
3  00:00:52    0  00:10:00/slot1                     2
4  00:10:01    0  00:20:00/slot2                     1
5  00:10:03    1  00:20:00/slot2                     1
6  00:10:05    0  00:20:00/slot2                     1
7  00:10:08    0  00:20:00/slot2                     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to avoid the complication of the Datetime comparison (unless that is your whole point, in which case ignore my answer), and show the essence of this group by slot window problem, I here assume times are integers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[8, 48, 250, 52, 1001, 1003, 1005, 1008, 2001, 2003, 2056], 
                   'gap': [1, 0,  1,   0,  0,    1,    0,    0,    1,    1,    1]})
slots = np.array([0, 1000, 1500])
df['slot'] = df.apply(func = lambda x: slots[np.argmax(slots[x['time']>slots])], axis=1)
df.groupby('slot')[['gap']].sum()
```

**Output**

```
       gap
slot    
-----------
0       2
1000    1
1500    3
```