# Append column values to match length with other data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have dataframe use length is 162430. Dataframe is like this.

```
 start_region_hash  Time  gap
               1   146    9
               1   163    7
               1   162   10
               1   144    5
               ........
               66    14    0
               66    17    0
               66    11    0
```

I want to add more columns of length 4800. I want to make their length 
162430.

```
    Date      Time        Weather  Temprature  PM2.5
 2016-01-01  00:00:28        1         4.0    177
 2016-01-01  00:05:24        1         3.0    177
 2016-01-01  00:10:08        1         3.0    177
 .......
 2016-01-21  23:45:44        2         1.0     59
 2016-01-21  23:50:31        2         1.0     59
 2016-01-21  23:55:26        2         1.0     59
```

Now what I want to do is match length of both new columns and original data by adding more rows in later. 
I know it is a but difficult. I want total length 162430. New data should be added with randomness but probability base. I am reading this data from files named with data. For example there are 278 rows of 2016-01-01 date but 40 rows of 2016-01-21. Total probability of new rows should be taken from len(2016-01-21).

Now for example in generating new rows, probability of 2016-01-21 is 2% because it has minimum rows and total rows it will contribute are 100. Now in generating these 100 rows, probability should be based on data of existing rows.

Comment: the fastest thing you can probably do is `np.random.choice(your_column_with_4800_rows, size=162430)`, you don't even need to calculate probabilities as they are intrinsic in the random data sample. `

Comment: can I do this with a dataframe? Dataframe h 5 columns.